# Word-wrapping comments in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, formatting, comments

```
/*
 *
 * This is a long comment. I broke it into lines, but that made it impossible to edit without screwing up the formatting. Is there a way to make Netbeans add line breaks automatically?
 *
 */
```

Reads: This is a long comment. I broke it into lines, but that made it impossible to edit without screwing up the formatting. Is there a way to make Netbeans add line breaks automatically?

Comment: What formatting are you talking about?

Comment: Reading that is just annoying ... (having to scoll).

Comment: Are you saying that you didn't manage to "format" your comment ? In other words, that you were not able to write a multi-line comment ?

Comment: Do you mean automatic formatters reformat your comments? If so, you should be able to turn that off (without knowing the Netbeans autoformatter).

Comment: @DarkDust, I can add new lines manually, but this makes editing hard. Adding/removing a couple of words from a manually line broken comment screws up the whole formatting.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 has the feature - cmd + opt + q

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for today, the current NetBeans (7.3) word-wraps comments with some nice available extra options when formatting. *NB: Unfortunately, this is currently only available for the Java language.*

You can launch the formatter with the context menu→`Format`, or if you did not change the standard shortcuts, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should do.

To access the corresponding configuration: `Tools` → `Options` → `Editor` → `Formatting`; `Language`: `Java`; `Category`: `Comments`

[image: Netbeans comments formatting options]

---

Comment: This only works for java I think, I do not see it under PHP or any other languages.

Comment: @nicholas.alipaz Thanks. Neither could I find it. I have added a note.

Comment: Category `Comments` does not exist in NetBeans 7.0.1 :(

Comment: By "automatically", you mean "when you run the format command"?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard well, yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This following StackOverflow question raises the issue re multi line comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911372/how-to-do-multi-line-comments-in-netbeans-without-auto-docblock-formatting and raised a bug with NetBeans for this to be fixed. NetBeans responded by fixing the issue for Java, but it was not fixed in PHP, and got re-opened. For those wanting the fix in PHP, add your voice via a vote or comment on the open NetBeans bug at  https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE won't format the comment for you. You will have to do it by hand. Yes, that means you have to re-format it once you add new words to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Enter to insert a new line, NetBeans will simply extend the docblock formatting - it won't break anything. There's also a useful option in the Preferences to display a line in the right margin, so you know when to break a line. It's in:

> Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting > Right Margin

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools->options->editor->formatting
find line wrap and choose one the wrapping style you desire,there are two options : afterword and anywhere.
and then click OK! :D

nb : I suggest you to choose afterword