# Netbeans (PHP): How to disable the imposed multi-lines comment syntax?

Tags: php, netbeans, syntax, comments, multiline

Whenever I want to write a multi-line comment within my PHP files, Netbeans throws some horrible commenting syntax on to my face.

I intend to write this:

```
/*
    This is a multi-line comment.
    That's how I do it, clear, simple, effective.
*/
```

But instead Netbeans forces me into having this:

```
/*
 * This is a multi-line comment.
 * That's what I wanna avoid, it's dirty, stupid, ineffective and ridiculous.
 */
```

I've tried looking at the different options but couldn't find anything related, even searching for "comment" in the options panel returns 0 results.

Is there any way to disable this horrible thing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm following this, some times it drives me crazy

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814 It will be possible in JAVA from 7.4, so maybe this functionality will also be present in PHP.

Comment: More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911372/how-to-do-multi-line-comments-in-netbeans-without-auto-docblock-formatting - also, please enter a comment and add a vote on the netbeans bug link posted above, so we can hopefully encourage them to fix this sooner rather than later