# How to turn off auto-complete block comments in NetBeans in PHP?

Tags: php, netbeans, javadoc

This question is **only about PHP, not for Java**.

NetBeans in PHP automatically completes block comments when I type `/*` rewriting  it like this:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

I really don't want any auto-completting after typing `/*` or `*/`. I know [there is a solution for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267552/104237) but I can't find any for PHP. Is it possible to turn off this feature please?

[image]

Comment: btw I use NetBeans 7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporary solution is to type `SHIFT + ENTER` after `/*`. It will not autocomplete the comment block.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is not yet possible if you are using NetBeans for PHP. This user had a similar question:
[How to do multi-line comments in NetBeans without auto DocBlock formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911372/how-to-do-multi-line-comments-in-netbeans-without-auto-docblock-formatting)

As you can see he submitted a bug report but scrolling down in the provided link shows that it was only corrected for Java so far:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814